# How to run a callback for navigation events in a Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to get a function to execute every time the user navigates to a new URL, but I can't get webNavigation to work for me. Here's what I'm trying so far:

manifest.json:

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "My Extension name",
  "description": "My Extension description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
  },
  "permissions": ["webNavigation"]
}
```

background.js:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate = function () {
    alert(123);
}
```

My breakpoint on the alert line never seems to hit. What am I doing wrong? Or is there another way to get an event every time the user navigates to a new page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webNavigation#event-onBeforeNavigate) is a chrome [`Event` object](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events).

To register a listener, you need to call `addListener`:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onBeforeNavigate.addListener(handler);

function handler(details) {
  alert(123);
}
```

Futhermore, take a look at [event filters](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/events#filtered).